# Drop or Paste file on the Textarea

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, riot.js

I want to make a message input like this.
[image]

But I have a question how to get file data, which I drag & drop or Ctrl+V on the textarea to upload.
I am using Riot.js and Symfony for this.

Here is my uncompleted code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="{ handleFileSubmit }">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="message" onpaste="{ handleFilePaste }" required> 
   </textarea>
</form>

handleFilePaste(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.clipboardData.items);
  console.log(window.navigator.clipboard);
}
```

But the above console.log() didn't get any file data when I copy a file on my local drive and paste it on the textarea.
If someone knows how to do it or have a good sample link, please share with me.

If you can, please share the drag & drop sample(important: the input field must be textarea).

I hope good replies.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I had to do something similar in the past I didn't attach the eventlistener to the form itself, but to `document` as shown in the example below (which you can execute and paste something, it works), technically I'm not sure if it works the same on a textarea but it does work on document, it's not that important where you listen for the paste event as you are then deciding what you do when you detect a file being pasted.

```js
function handleFilePaste(e) {

  const items = (e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  console.log(items);
  
  for (let index in items) {
    const item = items[index];
    if ( item.kind === 'file' ) {
      return item.getAsFile();
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.onpaste = function(e){
    const file = handleFilePaste(e);
    console.log(file);
    
    if ( !file ) { return; }
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="{ handleFileSubmit }">
   <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Paste something" required></textarea>
</form>
```